# ¿Qué argumentos debo dar en lugar de -t a mi comando de build Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Estoy intentando construir una imagen Docker a partir de un command dockerfile que recibia del desarollador anterior:

```
bash-5.1$ ls
data_collection  demonstrateur.ipynb  demo.py  Dockerfile  examples  README.md  requirements.txt  serious_game  start.py  test
bash-5.1$ docker build -t serious-game:0.0.1 -t serious-game:latest Dockerfile .
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

Soy un completo principiante en docker pero ¿por qué puso dos argumentos -t?
"-t", esto parece que dice al proceso principal dentro de docker que su entrada es un dispositivo de terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal y como está escrito en los [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options), Docker utiliza el archivo llamado *Dockerfile* por defecto. Si quieres especificar el archivo puedes usar la opción `--file` o `-f` del comando `docker build`.

En mi caso puedo usar simplemente **para resolver el problema**:

```
docker build -t serious-game:0.0.1 -t serious-game:latest .
```

Pero para especificar otro archivo llamado *TestDockerfile* (ejemplo para pruebas):

```
docker build -t serious-game:0.0.1 -t serious-game:latest -f TestDockerfile .
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dices de la terminal es para el subcomando `docker run`. Cada subcomando docker tiene sus propias opciones.

En el caso de `docker build` la opción `-t` es para ponerle un "tag" a la imagen resultante. Eso es el nombre por el que luego te podrás referir a ella (lo que suele incluir un número de versión).

Desde la versión 1.10 se puede repetir la opción `-t` para ponerle más de un "tag" (nombre).

Ya que a ti te ha dado error, eso indica que tienes una versión de docker muy antigua. Te recomendaría actualizarla. De todas formas, puedes también añadir tags a posteriori. Por ejemplo:

```
$ docker build -t serious-game:0.0.1 Dockerfile .
[...]

$ docker tag serious-game:0.0.1 serious-game:latest
```

El primer comando crea la imagen con el tag "serious-game:0.0.1" y una vez creada la imagen se le asigna otro tag con el comando  `docker tag`.

Comment: Muchas gracias abulafia! Y conoces vinculos o la command para actualizar la version de Docker?

Comment: Depende de cómo lo hayas instalado en la máquina. Pero en todo caso siempre puedes desinstalarlo (con el gestor de paquetes con que lo hubieras instalado) y volver a instalarlo "desde cero" siguiendo las instrucciones de https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/